# Error: Unable to parse JSON string when opening blackberry webworks application cod file in device after rebooting the blackberry device

Tags: blackberry-webworks

When we are trying to open the webworks application in a Blackberry device 9780 after rebooting the device, we are getting the error unable to parse JSON string.
The strange thing is that when we load our application in the device it runs absolutely fine but only when we reboot the device after that we are not able to run the application.

Breif explanation of our application which we are using:

We are using Blackberry Webworks Application and we compile the application using Blackberry Webworks SDK 2.3.1.5 to make the COD file. Then we sign that COD File using Blackberry JDE 5.0.0 and after that we load the COD file onto the Blackberry device 9780 using Javaloader.

If anyone has faced this kind of issue kindly reply.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems very strange.  Where is the JSON string being stored?  Is it possible that JSON string is being damaged or deleted on device reboot?  So, can you do a check to see whether the JSON string exists after the device reboot?

Thanks

Naveen M